# Sending mass email in PHP with Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

Still new to php and Laravel 4. I am working on an application using Laravel 4. In this application, I would like to send mass emails to many recipients. Is this possible using Laravel's framework or would it be better to look at other tools?

I have tried testing sending an email using Laravel's Mail::send() function with my own gmail but gmail blocked my attempt to sign in to my own account.

Comment: I'd just use Mandrill.com now - there is already a built in driver in Laravel 4 for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use [Mandrill.com](http://mandrill.com/) now - there is already a built in driver in Laravel 4 for it.

You can read how to [configure the driver in the Laravel 4 docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/mail#configuration).